Identify sitcom based on the theme song
Am trying to think of a sitcom that I must have watch around the early 90s.
It was either British or American, in colour, with a single mum, who may have been blonde, trying to raise quite a large family, which may have been mostly or all girls.
All I can remember vividly is the theme song was Lady Madonna by The Beatles.

Grace Under Fire used a cover of Lady Madonna by Aretha Franklin
Broad plotline fits - single mother [blonde] struggling to raise three children.
And broadcast period - '93 - '98
